# Unable to write Universal External (InstanceOf) object using AsnWriter

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, asn.1

I am currently using the built in [System.Formats.Asn1.AsnWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formats.asn1.asnwriter?view=net-6.0) provided by the latest .Net 6 framework and so far it has worked for all my needs except one, writing an Universal External Object.

Unless I'm missing something, all the provided writing methods except for [WriteEncodedValue(ReadOnlySpan)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formats.asn1.asnwriter.writeencodedvalue?view=net-6.0#system-formats-asn1-asnwriter-writeencodedvalue(system-readonlyspan((system-byte)))), guard against using any other [UniversalTagNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formats.asn1.universaltagnumber?view=net-6.0) except the expected UniversalTagNumber.

Is there any other way of encoding an `UniversalTagNumber.External` object using the AsnWriter?

My current workaround is to manually append (and by manually I mean adding the specific bits required) the `External` tag to my encoded external object and then use the `WriteEncodedValue` method to write the object. This works but I was wondering if there is a better way to approach this that does not rely on my to manually encode the tag.

Comment: If you can point to a specification that uses External and some reference encoded values, that would go well with a feature request at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues.

Comment: Assuming External works like SEQUENCE, I'd build it with as a Sequence, call Encode, then overwrite the tag.  But, I may be wrong.  (If I knew how External worked then it'd probably already be supported ;))